# Why is my ngFor loop not being entered even though the images are present?

Tags: angular

In have the following segment of code:

```
<section>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        BEFORE THE LOOP
        homeState.categories = {{homeState.categories}} //This is just a test
        <div class="col col-md-4 col-12 col-lg-4 mb-4" 
            *ngFor="let category of homeState.categories">
            INSIDE THE LOOP
            <div class="card">
                <img class="img-fluid card-img-top w-100 d-block" 
                    src="app/home/assets/img/{{category.img}}" style="height: 8rem;">
                <h4 style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;">{{category.name}}<br></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The 'BEFORE THE LOOP" comment is displayed.
This homeState.categories = {{homeState.categories}} displays the categories objects in the view.

But the "INSIDE THE LOOP" comment is not displayed. And the images of homeState.categories are never displayed.

homeState.categories originates from a redux store.

```
const initialState = {
categories: [
    {
        name: 'Ladies Apparel',
        img: '13.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Cards, Stationery & Gifts',
        img: '18.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Education',
        img: '19.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Electronics, Computers & Telephones',
        img: '20.jpg'
    },        
]
}
```

Comment: can you show the content of `homeState.categories` ?

Comment: @Random I have included homeState.categories.

Comment: Did you checked console? Maybe you forgot about import Common Module?

Comment: @koque name is displayed or not ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not actually sure if you can put that logic in your view. maybe you should try writting

> "homeState.categories = {{homeState.categories}}"

in the its components and remove this line from the view.

Comment: That line is only a test to make sure the categories are present in the view. It works, it displays the categories.